# Remove image reference from Xcode

Tags: xcode

I removed a few images from my **Assets.xcassets** folder but they still appear referenced when I want to change the image in an image view and I get a warning about the images. I did clean the project but still the same problem. I can't remove the entire assets folder in the build phases because i have other images that I use.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ignore it. That reference will disappear the next time you open Xcode or reboot OS X.